# REGEXP REPLACE Replace % with /%

Tags: sql, regex

I want to write a query using REGEXP_REPLACE function to replace special characters like %,!,*,etc. in a text by /special characters.

For example:
'100% Results' TO '100/% Results'

'ABC*D' to 'ABC/*D'

Can anyone please help.

I am using Oracle 11g.

Comment: Why do you want to use `REGEXP_REPLACE` and not just `REPLACE`? Also, have you looked up the syntax of the function you want to use? What have you tried so far, and what went wrong?

Comment: Then the one who defined those requirements is an idiot, pardon my French, or you misunderstood them. :)

Comment: What does "etc" mean? All non alphanumeric characters? (i.e. all characters except letters, numbers and space?)

Comment: @Jerry - Yes. It means that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the negated character class:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]
```

To mean any characters, except:

- characters from `a` to `z`,
- characters from `A` to `Z`,
- characters from `0` to `9`,
- spaces

---

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(text, '([^a-zA-Z0-9 ])', '/\1')
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7e420/9)

Comment: Thanks @Jerry. It works but when the text contains & or ', it does not.

Comment: @WamglindCarmasaic I'm not sure how it is not working? It looks to be working fine to me, see an [updated Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4c0b97/1)

Comment: I am using TOAD and it's not allowing me to Insert 'AB&D''asd'. It opens a window for substitution variable.

Comment: @WamglindCarmasaic Hmm, sorry I don't know much about TOAD :(

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(field, '%', '/%')
```